# Unit test should fail when string is a selected ordered subset of another string

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I am writing unit tests for the first time in visual studio 2013.

I am trying to write a test case to ensure that: The new password should not contain any 4 successive characters of user's full name.

Let's say the user's full name is: "John Yan", then if the user enters password "HnYa@123", it should fail.

Here is my code

```
[TestMethod]
public void Password_Contain_4_Successive_Characters_Of_User_FullName()
{
    UserInformation u = new UserInformation();
    string newPassword = "Mave@123";
    string username = "mary@mywebsite.com";
    var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(browserURL);
    ClickLink(browser, "Patient");
    ClickLink(browser, "here");
    EnterText(browser, "username", username);
    ClickButtion(browser, "Reset");
    browser.Close();
    var changePasswordBrowser = BrowserWindow.Launch(browserChangePasswordURL);
    EnterText(changePasswordBrowser, "UserLogin", username);
    EnterText(changePasswordBrowser, "TemporaryPassword", u.GetTemporaryPassword(username));
    EnterText(changePasswordBrowser, "NewPassword", newPassword);
    EnterText(changePasswordBrowser, "ConfirmNewPassword", newPassword);
    ClickButtion(changePasswordBrowser, "Submit");
    Assert.AreEqual(newPassword, u.GetUserPassword(username));

}
```

Which `Assert.` should I use, so the unit test gets failed if the new password contains 4 Successive characters of the user's full name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the currently accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691401/592182) seems to address your exact question, it doesn't feel like you are really asking the *right* question.  The point of unit testing is to ensure that your production logic does what you are expecting it to do.  It is not to implement your business logic.

Looking at your question, your requirement appears to be:

- When user sets a new password, ensure it doesn't contain 4 successive characters from the user's full name. (It is unclear what is supposed to happen when this occurs, but I would assume some kind of feedback to the user / failure response).

This is a business rule that needs to be implemented in your production code.  So, in Pseudo code, you would have:

```
if(StringContainsSuccessiveCharacters(newPassword, u.GetFullName(), 4)) {
    // Handle Error Situation
}
else {
    // Password is fine, proceed (save to db, do other checks etc)
}
```

In your tests, you would then supply different FullName and Passwords (such as in the tests cases by [@Ruskin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691518/592182)), in order to exercise your code and ensure that when the new password *did* contain 4 successive characters, an observable error scenario happened and that when it didn't a success scenario happened.  So, you might end up with some tests like this:

```
WhenPasswordContains4SuccessiveCharactersFromNameErrorShouldBeDisplayed() {
    string fullName = "John Yan";
    string newPassword = "HnYa@123";

    // Do setup stuff (mocks/browser etc)

    // Try and set password to newPassword

    // Validate that validation error was triggered
    // Which could be as simple as checking that the password isn't changed
}

PasswordCanBeChangedWhenAllValidationRulesPass() {
    string fullName = "John Yan";
    string newPassword = "ZYXW@123";

    // Do setup stuff (mocks/browser etc)

    // Try and set password to newPassword

    // Validate that success condition, such as navigating to new page
    // or that the password is actually updated.
}
```

The point is that your tests are there to make sure that your production code does what you want it to.  If you look at your example test in your question, you can see that you're supplying the value of `newPassword`.  You know at the point of writing the test whether or not `newPassword` contains the relevant characters from `FullName`.  Adding an assert for it doesn't test your production code, all it does is test that you've wired up your test correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one assert method, such that it fails if one string contains any consequent substring of another string. but you can implement this functional with following code

```
  var userName = u.GetUserPassword(username));
  for (int i = 0; i < userName.Length; ++i)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < userName.Length; ++j)
      if (newPassword.Contains(userName.Substring(i, j - i)))
        Assert.Fail();
```

Comment: @ManojSitapara Happy if so ))

Comment: @ManojSitapara P.S there is great Assertion framework for .NET, [Shouldly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Shouldly/) which makes testing lot more easier ))

Comment: Thank you I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

The above marked answer doesn't work with all the testcases below, try this:

```
[TestCase("Ruskin", "rusk")] // will fail test
[TestCase("Ruskin", "skin")] // will fail test
[TestCase("Ruskin", "Ruski")] // will fail test
[TestCase("Ruskin", "Ruskin")] // will fail test
[TestCase("John Yan", "HnYa@123")] // will fail test
[TestCase("Ruskin", "bob")] // will pass test
[TestCase("Ruskin", "ru5k")] // will pass test
[TestCase("Ruskin", "niks")] // will pass test
public void Password_Contain_4_Successive_Characters_Of_User_FullName(string userName, string password)
{
    var groupsOfFour = new List<string>();

    // do checks to make sure password/username are at least 4 characters etc

    string userNameWithoutSpaces = userName.Replace(" ", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < userNameWithoutSpaces.Length; i++)
    {
        groupsOfFour.Add(userNameWithoutSpaces.Substring(i, 4));

        if (i + 4 >= userNameWithoutSpaces.Length)
            break;
    }

    Assert.IsEmpty(groupsOfFour.Where(s => password.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1));
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use an answer to reply to a comment, even if you have a large swathe of code to post - and a very valid point. The correct way would be to comment and link to a gist/pastebin which hosts the code.